# Common Lisp: How to check if something is a type specifier?

Tags: types, common-lisp, predicate

I have been unable to find any built-in method of checking if something is a valid type specifier.

Does such a predicate exist?

(I would make one myself, but alas, the consequences of passing something not a type specifier to `typep` are undefined.  And `check-type` has no exceptional situations according to the hyperspec.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Tomohiro Matsuyama's [`trivial-types`](https://github.com/m2ym/trivial-types) system (LLGPL), which among other things defines a wrapper around some implementation-specific predicates:

```
(defun type-specifier-p (type-specifier)
  "Returns true if TYPE-SPECIFIER is a valid type specfiier."
  (or (documentation type-specifier 'type)
      #+sbcl (sb-ext:valid-type-specifier-p type-specifier)
      #+openmcl (ccl:type-specifier-p type-specifier)
      #+ecl (c::valid-type-specifier type-specifier)))
```

Answer (score 3):

To extend the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49728649/850781) to support [CLISP](http://clisp.org), use

```
#+clisp (null (nth-value 1 (ignore-errors (ext:type-expand type-specifier))))
```

See [Type Specifiers](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/types.html#type-spec).

Comment: I might submit a PR for this, unless you want to do it.